# Filter one collection based on another with AngularJS custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I need to filter a collection of objects based on another collection in angularjs.  I need to create a custom filter I'm sure but have found no examples that are similar.  So I have a list of "equipmentOptions" (basically they are product customizations, ex. premium stereo in your car).  Some "equipmentOptions" are not available unless you have already selected other "equipmentOptions".

The equipmentOptions available are $scope.product.equipmentOptions.
The equipmentOptions that have been selected are $scope.product.selectedOptions.

equipmentOptions has a property requiredParents which is a collection of id's for other equipment options.  If any of these requiredParents exist in $scope.product.selectedOptions, then the equipmentOption should be shown.

Here's what I've tried so far to no avail:

```
<div ng-repeat="option in product.equipmentOptions | optionsFilter:product.selectedOptions">
```

optionsFilter.js

```
myApp.filter('optionsFilter', function () {
return function (selectedOptions) {
    // I'm just trying to get the list of selected options as well as the current option here for filtering, how do I get the current option?
};
```

});

Comment: Please setup a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) which demonstrates the problem using sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first argument is the list of `product.equipmentOptions`. The second argument is `product.selectedOptions`. Write your filter like this:

```
myApp.filter('optionsFilter', function() {
  return function(equipmentOptions, selectedOptions) {
    var filteredOptions = [];
    angular.forEach(equipmentOptions, function(option) {
      if(/*option meets criteria*/) {
        filteredOptions.push(option);
      }
    });
    return filteredOptions;
  }
});
```